# Modal React-bootstrap now show from other component

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

O have a compnent that is a modal.

```
import { Modal } from "react-bootstrap";

function ModalDelete(show) {

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal show={show}>
        <Modal.Header>Hi</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>asdfasdf</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>This is the footer</Modal.Footer>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <button >Delete</button>
          <button>Save</button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>

  );
  
}

export default ModalDelete;
```

If i try to use inside other component, not works fine.
The screen goes to dark like the modal wants to show, but not appears.

If i copy the modal code inside the component where i want to show, the modal works.

I don't know what is happen.

The parent component:

```
function UploadImage({ input }) {       
    const onDrop = useCallback((file) => { 
      input.onChange(file);      
      getImages()
        .then(imagesFolder => {
          console.log(imagesFolder);
          if(imagesFolder.includes(file[0].name)){
            console.log('tengo tu imagen');
          }else{
            console.log('NO TENGO LA IMAGEN,,,,');
            setImage(file); 
          }
        })
        .catch (error => console.log(error));
    },[setImage]);

    const { getRootProps, getInputProps} = useDropzone({
      accept: "image/jpeg",
      noKeyboard: true,      
      onDrop,
    });
  
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const handleRemoveClick = () => {           
      setShow(true);
      console.log(show);
      
    };               
    
    return (  
      <div>
        {image.length === 0 ? (
          <div {...getRootProps()}>
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            <div className="btn btn-primary" >Click or Drag to Upload</div>
          </div>         
        ) :( 
          <div>
            <Modal show={show} />                  
            {image[0].name} <div className="btn btn-outline-danger ms-3" onClick={() => 
        handleRemoveClick()}><i className="bi bi-trash"></i> </div>  
          </div>
        )} 
      </div>           
    );
  }
```

maybe i need to do more things, but i don't know it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A react function component receives its props in the first argument sent to the function as an object, so when you write:

```
<Modal show={show} />
```

The modal component should look like:

```
function ModalDelete(props) {

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal show={props.show}>
        <Modal.Header>Hi</Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>asdfasdf</Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>This is the footer</Modal.Footer>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <button >Delete</button>
          <button>Save</button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This not works, i see the same behaviour of my component, dark the screen, but not show the modal.

Answer (score 0):

Update with response:

I have an error on my code, in my parent component i don't put the correct component.

Where is

```
return (  
      <div>
        {image.length === 0 ? (
          <div {...getRootProps()}>
            <input {...getInputProps()} />
            <div className="btn btn-primary" >Click or Drag to Upload</div>
          </div>         
        ) :( 
          <div>
            <Modal show={show} />                  
            {image[0].name} <div className="btn btn-outline-danger ms-3" onClick={() => 
        handleRemoveClick()}><i className="bi bi-trash"></i> </div>  
          </div>
        )} 
      </div>           
    );
```

i have to put

```
<ModalDelete show={show} />
```

That is the component where inside is the modal react-bootstrap.

Now works